# Insert and update in one query in mysql codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, codeigniter

I am new on codeigniter,I am doing the following things but I didn't get the solution.

Here is the following things one by one.

1. First I fetch the data from database and display in table format by foreach loop.

   ```
   <?php
   ```

   $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal','id'=>'update_form');
   echo form_open('emp_hodm_update/update_hodm', $attributes);
   ?>

   date
     Work
     Partner
     Director
     Time
     Task
     Status
     Action




       
       
         date;?>" class="" />
       
       
         work;?>" class="" />
       
       
         partner;?>" class="" />
       
       
         director;?>" class="" />
       
       
         time;?>" class="" />
       
       
         task;?>
       
       
         status;?>
       
       
         Delete
2. By clicking add button it creates new rows SO I want to update the old data as well as new row data which is created by add buttond to insert into a table.
3. But I didn't get any idea how to do this.

Controller:

```
public function update_hodm(){

/* Checking the all validation of task form*/
//$this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('work[]', 'Types of Work', 'required');
//$this->form_validation->set_rules('partner[]', 'Worked With', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('director[]', 'Director', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('time[]', 'No Of Hours', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('task[]', 'Task Details', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('status[]', 'Task Status', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
    /* Taking the data from form*/
    $todayDate = date('Y-m-d');
    $work=$this->input->post('work');
    $partner=$this->input->post('partner');
    $director=$this->input->post('director');
    $time=$this->input->post('time');
    $task=$this->input->post('task');
    $status=$this->input->post('status');

    $count=count($this->input->post('work'));
    $data =array();
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    $data[$i] = array(
        'name'       =>$this->session->userdata('emp_name'),
        'date'       =>$todayDate,
        'work'       =>$work[$i],
        'partner'    =>$partner[$i],
        'director'   =>$director[$i],
        'time'       =>$time[$i],
        'task'       =>$task[$i],
        'status'     =>$status[$i]
        );
        }
        $add=$this->update->update_hodm($data,$todayDate);
        /* Display Success message if data updated successfully in database*/

            if($add){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form',"All HODM Data Inserted Successfully.");
                $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form_class','alert-success');
            }else{
                /* Displaying the error message*/
                $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form',"failed to add, Please Try again");
                $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form_class','alert-danger');
            }
        return redirect('home');
} else {
    $this->load->view('public/digital_hodm_view');
}
}
```

Model:

```
public function update_hodm($data,$todayDate){
        $this->db->where('date',$todaydate);
        $this->db->update_batch('task_form', $data,'date');//date is my table column name 
        return true;
    }
```

4. Please help me to find the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need to update the old data when add button is clicked? Just create an add function in controller and call that when add button is clicked

Comment: You dont actually mention what the problem is! Apart from _But I didn't get any idea how to do this._ In which case the solution is to hit the books

Comment: @Sultan you didn't get me.When i clicked on add button then it creates new row of same column blank . after filling the new row and changing in old row when i clicked the submit button then it goes into table with old data and new data

Comment: Is update is working?

Comment: @aman no update is also not working.

Comment: is there any one available.

Comment: Try to user a flag variable that determine you PHP script about the rows status,flag variable will give an idea that these row are for updation and other rows for insertion then with the help of flag value separate the values in different array variable for insertion and updation.

Comment: @aman . I dont know how to do this..it already took my whole day..please help

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html check this.. you can make query this way

Comment: Could you plz share your tables from which you are inserting and updating you record

Comment: @aman .  form_id , name , date , work, partner,director,time, task, status ... These are columns in my table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code for view see 
add one more column updated_at

View:

```
<?php
        $attributes = array('class' => 'form-horizontal','id'=>'update_form');
        echo form_open('emp_hodm_update/update_hodm', $attributes);
        ?>
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
        <thead>
        <tr class="">
          <th>date</th>
          <th>Work</th>
          <th>Partner</th>
          <th>Director</th>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Task</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach($result as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
            <td>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="date[]" value="<?php echo $row->date;?>" class="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="work[]" value="<?php echo $row->work;?>" class="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="partner[]" value="<?php echo $row->partner;?>" class="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="director[]" value="<?php echo $row->director;?>" class="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="time[]" value="<?php echo $row->time;?>" class="" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <textarea class="form-control" name="task[]" rows="2" id=""><?php echo $row->task;?></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
              <textarea class="form-control" name="status[]" rows="2" id=""><?php echo $row->status;?></textarea>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>

    <!-- Add This -->
              <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="form_id_hidden[]" value="<?php echo $row->form_id;?>"

            </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
        </table> 
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
        <?php 
        echo form_close();
        ?>
```

Controller :

```
    public function update_hodm(){

    /* Checking the all validation of task form*/
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('work[]', 'Types of Work', 'required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('partner[]', 'Worked With', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('director[]', 'Director', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('time[]', 'No Of Hours', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('task[]', 'Task Details', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('status[]', 'Task Status', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
      /* Taking the data from form*/
                $todayDate = date('Y-m-d'); 

                <!-- Add This -->
                $updatedDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // if not used H:i:s and there is no chnage in data update will return false

                $work=$this->input->post('work');
                $partner=$this->input->post('partner');
                $director=$this->input->post('director');
                $time=$this->input->post('time');
                $task=$this->input->post('task');
                $status=$this->input->post('status');

                <!-- Add This -->
                $form_id=$this->input->post('form_id_hidden');

                $count=count($this->input->post('work'));

                <!-- Add This -->
                $data = $new_data = array();
                $old_ids = array();

                for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {

                    <!-- Add This -->

                    if(!in_array($form_id[$i],$old_ids)){
                      $old_ids[] = $form_id[$i];

                $data[$i] = array(
                    'name'       =>$this->session->userdata('emp_name'),
                    'date'       =>$todayDate,
                    'work'       =>$work[$i],
                    'partner'    =>$partner[$i],
                    'director'   =>$director[$i],
                    'time'       =>$time[$i],
                    'task'       =>$task[$i],
                    'status'     =>$status[$i],
                    'form_id'    =>$form_id[$i],
                    'updated_at' =>$updatedDate,
                    );
                 }else{
                    $new_data[$i] = array(
                    'name'       =>$this->session->userdata('emp_name'),
                    'date'       =>$todayDate,
                    'work'       =>$work[$i],
                    'partner'    =>$partner[$i],
                    'director'   =>$director[$i],
                    'time'       =>$time[$i],
                    'task'       =>$task[$i],
                    'status'     =>$status[$i],
                    );
                 }
            }

            <!-- Add This -->

           $update=$this->update->update_hodm($data,'form_id');
           $add = $this->update->addnew_hodm($new_data);
            /* Display Success message if data updated successfully in database*/

                    if($update && $add){   <!-- Add This -->
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form',"All HODM Data  Updated  and Inserted Successfully.");
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form_class','alert-success');

                       }else if($update){  <!-- Add This -->
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form',"All HODM Data Updated Successfully.");
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form_class','alert-success');
                        }
                        else if($add){   
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form',"All HODM Data Inserted Successfully.");
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form_class','alert-success');
                        }else{
                            /* Displaying the error message*/
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form',"failed to add, Please Try again");
                            $this->session->set_flashdata('hodm_form_class','alert-danger');
                        }
            return redirect('home');
    } else {
        $this->load->view('public/digital_hodm_view');
    }
    }

Model :

<!-- Add This --> 
    public function addnew_hodm($data){
        if(empty($data)){
            return false;
        }
        $this->db->insert_batch('task_form', $data); 
        return ($this->db->affected_rows()>0?TRUE:FALSE);
    }

    <!-- Add This -->
    public function update_hodm($data,$where){
        if(empty($data)){
            return false;
        }
        $this->db->update_batch('task_form', $data,$where); 
        return ($this->db->affected_rows()?TRUE:FALSE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is unique/primary key in that table, add the key for each data. Assuming the key is `task_id`, update the code in your controller:

```
    ...
    ...
    ...
    'task'       =>$task[$i],
    'status'     =>$status[$i]
    );  
    if(!empty($task_id[$i]))$data[$i]['task_id'] = $task_id[$i]; //Add task ids for old data
   }
   $add=$this->update->update_hodm($data,$todayDate);
```

In your model, update the function with following code:

```
foreach($data as $array)
{
  $query = 'INSERT INTO `table` SET ';
  $sep = $setvalues = '';
  foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    $setvalues .=  $sep.$key.' = "'.$value.'"';
    $sep = ',';
  }
  $query .= $setvalues.' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '.$setvalues.';';      
  $this->db->query($query);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**VIEW :**

```
<?php
$attributes = array(
    'class' => 'form-horizontal',
    'id' => 'update_form'
);
echo form_open('emp_hodm_update/update_hodm', $attributes);
?>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive">
<thead>
<tr class="">
  <th>date</th>
  <th>Work</th>
  <th>Partner</th>
  <th>Director</th>
  <th>Time</th>
  <th>Task</th>
  <th>Status</th>
  <th>Action</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php

foreach($result as $row)
    { ?>
    <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="form_id[]" value="<?php
    echo $row->form_id; ?>" class="" />
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="date[]" value="<?php
    echo $row->date; ?>" class="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="work[]" value="<?php
    echo $row->work; ?>" class="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="partner[]" value="<?php
    echo $row->partner; ?>" class="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="director[]" value="<?php
    echo $row->director; ?>" class="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="time[]" value="<?php
    echo $row->time; ?>" class="" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="task[]" rows="2" id=""><?php
    echo $row->task; ?></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="status[]" rows="2" id=""><?php
    echo $row->status; ?></textarea>
    </td>
    <td>
      <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <!--
    start :if extra row is add on the button click 
    -->
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="date[]" value="" class="" />
            <!--
            make sure at time of addition value of form_id[] should be empty
            -->
            <input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="form_id[]" value="" class="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="work[]" value="" class="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="partner[]" value="" class="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="director[]" value="" class="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="time[]" value="" class="" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="task[]" rows="2" id=""></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="status[]" rows="2" id=""></textarea>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <!--
    end :
    -->
<?php
    } ?>
</tbody>
</table> 
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="add">
<?php
echo form_close();
?>
```

**Controller:**

```
public function update_hodm(){
    /* Checking the all validation of task form*/

    // $this->form_validation->set_rules('date', 'Date', 'required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('work[]', 'Types of Work', 'required');

    // $this->form_validation->set_rules('partner[]', 'Worked With', 'required');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('director[]', 'Director', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('time[]', 'No Of Hours', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('task[]', 'Task Details', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('status[]', 'Task Status', 'required');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        foreach($_POST['form_id'] as $key => $value) {
            $data = array(
                'name' => 'aman',
                'date' => $_POST['date'][$key],
                'work' => $_POST['work'][$key],
                'partner' => $_POST['partner'][$key],
                'director' => $_POST['director'][$key],
                'time' => $_POST['time'][$key],
                'task' => $_POST['task'][$key],
                'status' => $_POST['status'][$key]
            );
            if (!empty($value)) {

                // update

                $this->update->update_hodm($data, $value);
            }
            else {

                // insert

                $this->update->insert_hodm($data);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $this->load->view('public/digital_hodm_view');
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function update_hodm($data,$form_id){
        $this->db->where('form_id',$form_id);
        $this->db->update_batch('task_form', $data,'date');//date is my table column name 
        return true;
}

public function insert_hodm($data){
      $this->db->insert('task_form', $data);name 
      return true;
}
```

Comment: I'm not exactly sure that this will exactly work which you want , because most of the thing I have assume and then code, but this is almost what you wanted as I could understand from you question,hope it will work for you.Tell me if an extra help need